# Datatype preservation not working with json serialization in row and column format

Tags: json, coldfusion, coldfusion-11

The [ColdFusion 11 documentation](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-s/serializejson.html) states that *"..Starting from ColdFusion 11, the data type is preserved during the code execution time for Query and CFCs."*

I have tried:

```
<cfquery name="qry_Users" datasource="cse">
 SELECT name,cgpa
 FROM   student_cgpa
 WHERE  ID IN (1)
</cfquery>

<cfdump var="#getmetadata(qry_Users)#">
<cfoutput>
  Row: #serializeJSON(qry_Users,"row")#<br>
  Struct: #serializeJSON(qry_Users,"struct")#
</cfoutput>
```

Here both name and cgpa are varchar fields. You see for row wise serialization it is not preserving the datatype of cgpa but working for struct type serialization.

Is not this unexpected?

[image]

Comment: I'd say it is NOT expected. File a bug report please.